# Unable to install android studio dependency is not satisfiable

Tags: apt, package-management, android, dependencies

I am trying to install android studio from [this](http://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/) source:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 android-studio : Depends: lib32ncurses5 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: lib32stdc++6 but it is not installable
                  Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not installable
                  Depends: lib32z1 but it is not installable
                  Depends: lib32z1-dev but it is not installable
```

I tried to install them but then it gives me this error for each missing package:

```
Package lib32ncurses5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. I ran ````sudo apt-get update````.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution by installing Android Studio from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)

Comment: I also used this method to successfully install Android Studio - would have prefered the ````apt-get```` method, though.

Answer (score 0):

This link will work only for 64bit when it comes to 32bit we are still facing the problem.

Will post the remedy soon.